# Programmatically Populate Google Sheet Row anytime a specific alert occurs in Google Alert Center

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to figure out how to automatically pull data from our Google Alert Center anytime a specific alert happens.

EX: User Suspended for Spam

Trigger- New alert, user suspended for spam
Action- Get data, populate new row in google sheet with event details [date, affected user, event description]

Using this to automate the report retrieval process, rather than having to do a manual export every-time this event occurs.

Comment: Have you look at [Alert Center API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/alertcenter/reference/rest)

Comment: What have you tried so far? What tools do you want to use? [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script)? [Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api)? You will need to complement either of these with Alert Center API.